# reading data that may have been updated concurrently

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

In my Blazor app, I am reading rows from a Database View using a `DbSet<EntityName>`. However, updates to the data must be done by stored procedure calls (this requirement is out of my control), not through the DbSet. I am invoking the stored procedures through the same `DbContext` using `context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("exec ...");`.

Is it necessary to signal somehow to the `DbSet` that the underlying data of the View may have been changed ?

In testing my app: if I call a stored procedure to update the data, and then call `.Where(...).ToListAsync()` again on the `DbSet`, it does retrieve the updated changes -- indicating that the EFCore framework did actually decide to query the database again for the data. But I am concerned that it might in some other circumstance decide to return values from internal cache instead of making another database call.

Comment: It may not retrieve new data if tracked entities are in `Modified` state. Otherwise everything should be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For read operations promote using `AsNoTracking()`. This will ensure that the read always fetches the current data state and will ignore any entities that happen to be in the tracking cache.

If you do need to manage updates through both the DbSets and things like Stored Procedures or external actors then you will need to consider something like a concurrency token like RowVersion/Timestamp. This way if you do want to apply changes via the DbSet you can first query the concurrency token for the row and compare against the current loaded entity. If the value differs then you can handle the scenario for the fact that the underlying data has changed since the entity was loaded and tracked. EF will also reject an update if the concurrency token is configured and has been updated. (For those race conditions where a change goes in between checking and comitting)